# NVIDIA RTX 3060 owners, do some of the colors flicker in your Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04

This is a fresh 22.04 LTS install. X11 windowing. RTX 3060 graphics. I have enabled the NVIDIA drivers (510) and rebooted. After that certain colors seem to flicker. For example some of the colors on this wallpaper are subtly flickering as shown in the video. Please note, you will have to download the video as Google player reduces the size and hides the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbkamSoF8PN6RBJWTN9tHMnEXxE2eArr/view?usp=sharing

Here is the actual wallpaper if you want to test on your system (please view in full screen): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRqnY.jpg

It is NOT easy to detect(!) as it affects just certain tones. You don't notice it until you look closer. Easy to spot in low light. As you can see in the video, 90% of the colors are stable, just some are flickering.

- I am wondering if anyone with RTX 3060 had the same type of subtle flickering in the past releases?
- Did you found the solution to this problem?

I actually spent whole yesterday reading the archive and searching about the flicker problem. Everyone is referring to either screen going blank for a while or skipping areas. I didn't found similar problem referenced before which makes me believe it's a newer bug. To make things worse, it is not easy to detect!

Also to clear something out, the card is fine. It does not show any flickering on Windblows 10. In both cases it is set at 60 Hz refresh rate, 1920x1080, DP connection. Windoze video of the same image shows no flickering:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10VOCUd6zQ9oC7hBgfM7y_uyDnHSqyZZP/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE: I believe I found the source of the problem.

Monitors are Dell U2422H. From my research, many panels used in monitors are really 6bit per color channel. The 8bit color range is then somewhat faked and done through the monitor making the pixels flicker between different colors. And perhaps that's happening in my case. The problem is related to dithering mode.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution.

So if you experience any color band flickering on Nvidia, just disable the dithering. This option is somewhat hidden under the GPU 0 settings / Controls. Set to Disabled and the problem is gone.

[image: Dithering setting]

Odd thing, I actually found the solution via my own post from few years ago about gamma issue where someone pointed me to another thread which then made me learn about the dithering issues and in which direction to look -> it was a dithering issue, rather than color issue. The rest was easy. This board rocks! Thanks!